# Connecting Fingerprint Scanner through Ethernet

Tags: networking, fingerprint

I have installed zkt same software from [This Link](https://archive.org/details/ZKTime5.0NEW29122015) as used in [This Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dtFBu6U1Xo) also i have tried different versions from  official link like
ZKTnet 3.0 zkt -web2.0

I can successfully ping my fingerprint device ip from cmd

But it fails to connect using zkt software. I am using default port 4370. Plz have a look at screenshot[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Redacting an IP which is shown in each reply? You could try to use `telnet <ip> 4370` to check whenever you can establish a connection. If not your target most likely doesn't serve anything on that port and you'll have to check the device that has the IP for its setting/firewall blocks.